# Computing odds ratios for multiple dichotomous DVs in a within-person, mixed-effects design?

Tags: logistic, lme4-nlme, likelihood, odds-ratio

I have an experiment where people participate in a series of tasks (say 4) and then are scored based on their performance (pass/fail). The order of the tasks is randomized. I want to predict likelihood of passing on a given task based on whether they have previous experience with that task (Yes/No).

I have generated some data below similar to what I am working with.

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 
49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 
53L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 
58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 
62L, 62L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 
66L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 
71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 
79L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 
88L, 88L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 91L, 91L, 91L), task = c("task1", 
"task2", "task3", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task2", 
"task3", "task1", "task3", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task2", 
"task1", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task1", 
"task3", "task2", "task3", "task2", "task1", "task2", "task1", 
"task3", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task3", "task1", "task2", 
"task1", "task3", "task2", "task1", "task3", "task2", "task1", 
"task3", "task2", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task1", "task2", 
"task3", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task1", "task3", "task2", 
"task3", "task1", "task2", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task3", 
"task1", "task2", "task1", "task3", "task2", "task3", "task2", 
"task1", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task3", "task2", 
"task3", "task1", "task2", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task1", 
"task2", "task3", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task1", "task2", 
"task3", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task3", "task2", "task1", 
"task1", "task3", "task2", "task2", "task1", "task3", "task1", 
"task2", "task3", "task1", "task3", "task2", "task1", "task3", 
"task2", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task2", "task3", 
"task3", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task2", "task1", "task2", 
"task1", "task3", "task2", "task1", "task3", "task3", "task1", 
"task2", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task3", "task2", "task1", 
"task3", "task1", "task2", "task1", "task3", "task2", "task3", 
"task2", "task1", "task3", "task2", "task1", "task3", "task1", 
"task2", "task2", "task1", "task3", "task3", "task1", "task2", 
"task3", "task2", "task1", "task2", "task1", "task3", "task3", 
"task2", "task1", "task1", "task3", "task2", "task3", "task1", 
"task2", "task1", "task3", "task2", "task1", "task2", "task3", 
"task1", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task1", 
"task2", "task3", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task2", "task1", 
"task3", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task1", 
"task2", "task3", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task1", 
"task3", "task2", "task3", "task1", "task2", "task3", "task1", 
"task2", "task3", "task2", "task1", "task1", "task2", "task3", 
"task2", "task3", "task1", "task1", "task3", "task2", "task2", 
"task3", "task1", "task3", "task2", "task1", "task1", "task2", 
"task3"), prevxp = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, NA, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, NA, 1, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1), passfail = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-240L), class = "data.frame")
```

My original inclination was to analyse it using `glmer` logistic regression, like this:

```
mod <- lme4::glmer(passfail ~ prevxp:task + (1|id), 
                          family = binomial(link='logit'),
                          data = df)

jtools::summ(mod)
r2glmm::r2beta(mod)
```

Which yields these results:

```
FIXED EFFECTS:
-----------------------------------------------------
                          Est.   S.E.   z val.      p
---------------------- ------- ------ -------- ------
(Intercept)              -1.12   0.52    -2.17   0.03
prevxp:tasktask1         -1.50   0.78    -1.93   0.05
prevxp:tasktask2         -0.85   0.56    -1.53   0.13
prevxp:tasktask3          0.04   0.54     0.08   0.94
```

I used this because I want to account for the within-person effects--ie that someone might have more experience with more tasks and their scores would be more highly correlated. This is in contrast to computing chi-squares for each task.
I included only the interaction between `prevxp` and `task` because I literally only care about a task *given* prevxp. But am open to comments whether this is appropriate.

Questions:

1. Is this the best way to analyse the data? How else could I analyse this data? For example, I don't like that one of my tasks becomes the "reference group"
2. Importantly, I also looked at the counts for `prevxp` given `task`
   and the number of people in each category does not seem to match up
   to the results. For example:

```
dplyr::group_by(df, task,prevxp) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(n())

    
    task prevxp n()
1   task1   0   42
2   task1   1   34
3   task1   NA  4
4   task2   0   2
5   task2   1   73
6   task2   NA  5
7   task3   0   7
8   task3   1   68
9   task3   NA  5
```

So Task 2 shows 2 vs 73 (in prevxp vs none). Yet, in the output above, Task 2 shows B = -.85, p = .13, sR2 = .012.  I think this is because each task is being compared to Task 4 and I don't want this comparison.

How do I compute the likelihood for each task while controlling for the within-person correlations across tasks?